# Динамические поддомены через .htaccess (mod_rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Нужно чтобы по адресу `user1.site.ru` выдавалось содержимое `site.ru/users.php?login=user1` . Соответственно, вместо `user1` может быть что угодно. Простой дешёвый хост за 3 сотки, то есть доступа ко внутренностям нет. Автоподдомены включил (*.site.ru), проблема в .htaccess, в нём не шарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

От вас дождёшься...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.ru$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.site\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/users.php?login=%1 [L,P]
```